# Posting javascript to a database

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

I am trying to get a javascript variable into my sql server database using ajax and php and jquery.  Does anybody know how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, it's very simple. Use the `.post` function:

```
$.post("somefile.php", { someVar: yourVariable }, function() {
    //Done!
});
```

I'm assuming that by "get a javascript variable into database" you mean the *value* of the variable.

In `somefile.php` you can access the variable with `$_POST["someVar"]`.

Comment: i tried that before but instead of , {someVar: yourVariable} ,  i just had  , yourVariable,  ill try it with that adjustment

Comment: I have this   $.post("attend_ajax.php",{pass:input},function(data)
                 {
                    alert(data);
                 });                                                           then in php i have  $data=$_POST["pass"];  I have it return the result of my sql call and it says that the index of pass is undefined.  I have checked the input variable and it is a valid array.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript (and jQuery):

```
function postValues() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'someurl.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({ javascript_variable: $('#someid').val() })
    });
}
```

PHP (in a file named someurlphp, or whatever you want to call it, just make sure your jquery ajax call is calling the correct file)

```
<?php
    $sql = sprintf(
        'INSERT INTO sometable
         SET some_col = "%s"',
         mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['javascript_variable']));
    mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: ... Why is [most] everyone [who uses PHP] so bent on *not* using placeholders? :(

Answer (score 0):

You call Jquery's post method in your javaScript:
`$.post("update.php", { name: "John Doe"}, function() {});`

And then update.php contains something like this (Assuming MySQL):

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (Name)
VALUES ('$name')");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: thank you but i am not using mysql.  my problem is the post is simply not working. i have tried everything.  $.post("attend_ajax.php",{'params':param[key],'action':key})  then in php $data=$_POST['params'];  $key=$_POST['action'];  and neither of these are set.  it fails every time no matter how i adjust it.  ive checked my arrays in javascript and they are good to go.  i have another project where i do the exact same thing(i copied that code into this project) but in this project it wont work :-(